# When is a continuous phase transition in a translationally-invariant 2$d$ classical spin system not described by a CFT?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, phase-transition

I'm trying to better understand when I should expect conformal invariance to emerge at a continuous phase transition.

I'm imagining classical, $q$-state spins living on the vertices of a 2d square lattice with nearest-neighbor interactions. The system has discrete translational invariance on shifting the lattice by either a horizontal step or a vertical step. Assume the system undergoes a continuous phase transition at some temperature $T_c$.

Is the long-wavelength behavior of this model necessarily described by a conformal field theory?

---

Note that **I'm allowing anisotropy** in the sense that the vertical couplings can have a different magnitude than the horizontal couplings. However, all the same, I'm having trouble finding an example that is not described by a conformal field theory.

The isotropic Ising model and the $q=3,4$ state Potts models are all described by CFTs. The $q>4$ Potts models are not described by CFTs, but they don't have continuous phase transitions so they don't give a counterexample.

The anisotropic Ising model appears to again be described by a CFT, the same CFT as the isotropic Ising model. I'm not sure about the anisotropic $q=3,4$ state Potts models, but I expect they're described by the same CFTs as their respective isotropic versions.

I feel there has to be an example, but I'm having a hard time coming up with one.

Comment: It's hard to get away from CFTs especially in two dimensions: https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1087. By analytically continuing parameters of some familiar lattice models, there are examples of *logarithmic* CFTs at the critical point. And the extreme case of anisotropy would be cutting off space to get a *boundary* CFT.

Comment: @ConnorBehan That's a nice article! I guess I feel like the proof for having a CFT follows from the properties of the stress-energy tensor being fixed by Lorentz invariance and scale invariance. If I have anisotropy, I feel like I'm not guaranteed the rotational part of Lorentz invariance, and so that the proof wouldn't apply. Could you also discuss a little more of the extreme case of anisotropy? If I turned off the couplings in one direction, I'd have decoupled 1d models, none of which would undergo a transition.

Comment: That's a solid argument. Yes, strong enough anisotropy probably does allow plenty of critical points not described by a CFT. I don't know much about lattice realizations. But there's a decent amount of literature about the Galilean conformal group, Schroedinger group etc which apply to CFT-like systems with different Lifshitz exponents.